# How to limit the use of an app to one device on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have currently an app that through in-app purchases a user can unlock content on the app. What I have noticed is that some users "abuse" of this by logging with their Apple ID in multiple devices and I'm currently looking into possibilities on how to limit the use of the content to the device where the purchase was done. I understand that Apple doesn't allow that, so that means the payment system should go away from the app.

Therefore, introducing logging will help me to be able to identify the person that is using the app against a backend but still, I need to be able to limit on a device. As far as I know, the UUIDString of the CurrentDevice is not really a way anymore. What other options are?
I saw this library, which seems to promise unique identification:
https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/FCUUID

Another solution probably would be to create a licensing system, so one license can only be used at the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not allow a user to use an app they paid for? Why does it matter if they user runs your app on more than one of the devices they have?

Comment: Because the purchase you do is a subscription for a year that allows you to have all the content that cost quite some money available. Some people, runs this in more than 10 devices which basically means, I'm not profiting of it. It's the same as if you buy a license for some software, you can't use it in more than one computer, right? So that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are going to spend your time and effort and make purchasing harder for users - since they won't be able to subscribe on the device, they will need to find a web site that you can't direct them to in your app to make the payment.  Plus you need some process for handling the case where the user legitimately changes device (e.g. new phone).  You may find that this actually costs you subscribers, rather than creating new ones.  The code you linked to uses uuid and the keychain, so it will probably work for you;it is quite old and written in Objective C so, it may not work "out of the box".

Comment: I understand that... I don't think it's a problem to do it through the website since users already use the website for getting some of the content created by the device. As well, it's indeed a problem when users change the device but I can imagine some cases are acceptable(f.e. requesting a new license every day will not be really normal).
I've checked that library and it works perfectly in Swift, it actually generates a UUID that persists even uninstalling the app but probably, when doing a backup, it will be transfered.

Comment: Something to consider if you make the payment system 'go away from the app' is that Apple specifically states "Subscribers who were acquired outside of your app can read or play content through the app. However, you may not provide external links in your app that allow users to purchase subscriptions outside of the app."

Answer (score 4):

I will describe our experience with using same account on different devices (VOD):
User is able to use application on how many devices he want, but he able to watch content only on 5 uniq devices.
Each time user try to watch content, app check if device registered with some UUID, if not then try to register. UUID is uniq per installation, it mean that if user will watch content, then delete app, download again and watch, then he basically lose 1 device.
In same time user able to unregister device via web, but he had only like 25 unregistrations (I don't know what happened if user use them all).
We don't use in-app purchases and accounts are cross-platform (android, iOS, web, tvs, etc), so not sure if it helps you.

Comment: Very useful! This goes in the direction of what we wanted to do. Do you store that UUID somewhere apart from UserDefaults?

Comment: You shouldn't store anything except application settings in `UserDefaults`. Proper place for sensitive data is Keychain

Comment: This is exactly what we need, but i taught that when you use your own account system with external payment, you need to offer the same thing within the in-app purchase.

Comment: @hugo411 no you dont need to. But in such case you cannot have any references to payment in your app (aka “signup on web”, in which payment is required)

Comment: Alright thanks. In my case the app is free but i have paid features which require full version bought on our website. Same as you, there is a device limitation on one account and we are cross-platform accross android,ios,mac,pc. I guess when the user login, you make the attribution directly? because we cannot have any activation process using third party. (from what i see on the docs).

Comment: @hugo411 what you mean by "attribution"?

Comment: Sorry i mean link the device to the account, taking a spot on your 5 devices limitation.

Comment: @hugo411we register device only in moment when user access protected content (play movie in our case) via our backend

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Apple does not have limit on how many devices you can user Apple Id. You can have 6 family members so number of devices could be lot more.

I feel it is bias how Apple's guideline talks about limiting music, movies, shows and books to 10 devices but does not say anything about Apps!

[Apple - Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201060)

> If your family has purchase sharing turned on, music, movies, TV shows, and books can be downloaded on up to 10 devices per account, five of which can be computers.

**I have not seen any application limiting IAP on devices. You could run into risk of Apple rejecting your app, potentially on every update you submit. I would reach out to App Store or if your company have Sales rep contact and get their suggestions/buy-in before spending lot of time and money.**

**Also, create issue/radar and give specifics about issue. More people request this feature, has better chances of it getting added.**

One way you can achieve this is to keep track of receipt you get for IAP and check how many users/devices using that receipt. You would need to build entire flow to educate user about device limitations. Like updating App Store page, warning before purchasing, option to add/remove device and more...

**If you are planning to implement device limitation, please beware of the rejection risk.**

Comment: Makes sense what you say but this would be in the case we keep using IAP. Therefore, a solution would be to stop using IAP, make the payment through the website and generate some sort of license that can only be used at one device at the time. That way, if my understanding is correct, would not be a problem for Apple since we are not limiting with IAP, which is the main "problem" here. Right?

Comment: I would think so. However, removing IAP and doing external payments will introduce other problems as Apple wants devs to use IAP to get 30% cut!!. Spotify is been fighting with them forever on this. I think safe bait is to reach out Apple dev/engineer/sales to get their buy-in to get directions on this.

Comment: Create issue/radar give specifics. More people request this feature, has better chances of it getting added.